# JS Insert string variable into another one

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

For a recent project, the client wants to be able to design and send emails, using data from the database, for the sake of this example let's say it's an invoce, and he wants the client's name

To avoid having the email string as a variable in the JS code (using``), I want to store it either on the database, or as a file

This comes with the problem of adding the data from the database into it, I know you can use the `` simbols and then wrap the variable like ${var}, but would it still work if the string is stored in a variable that i got from the database?

I'm using NodeJS 18 with MySql and Sequelize

This is my current code, but I'm not sure if it'll work

```
let client = await Client.findOne({
    where:{
        id_client:req.params.id
    }
})

let email = await Email.findOne({
    where:{
        template_name:'invoice'
    }
})
const mailOptions={
    from:`"Fake Company", "no-reply@fakecompany.com"`,
    to: client.email,
    subject: 'Invoice',
    html: `${email.template_body}`
}
```

So I guess my real question is:

If the string in `${email.template_body}` is something like `<body><h1>${client.name}</h1></body>` will the client's name get inserted? Or what would be the correct aproach?

Comment: No, template literals are evaluated at declaration time. You'll need to use a _replace_ operation to substitute placeholders in a string literal